# Create results grid from database tables: SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which describes patients' medical symptoms which has the following structure.
Note that patient 1 and patient 2 have two symptoms.

```
| patientID | symptomName    | SymptomStartDate | SymptomDuration |
|-----------|----------------|------------------|-----------------|
| 1         | Fever          | 01/01/2020       | 10              |
| 1         | Cough          | 02/01/2020       | 5               |
| 2         | ChestPain      | 03/01/2020       | 6               |
| 2         | DryEyes        | 04/01/2020       | 8               |
| 3         | SoreThroat     | 05/01/2020       | 2               |
| 4         | AnotherSymptom | 06/01/2020       | 1               |
```

Using this data, I want to create a grid showing which symptoms each patient had, in the following format (with 1 indicating that the patient had that symptom and 0 indicating that the patient did not have that symptom)

```
| patientID | Fever | Cough | ChestPain | DryEyes | SoreThroat | AnotherSymptom |Headache|
|-----------|-------|-------|-----------|---------|------------|----------------|--------|
| 1         | 1     | 1     | 0         | 0       | 0          | 0              |0       |
| 2         | 0     | 0     | 1         | 1       | 0          | 0              |0       |
| 3         | 0     | 0     | 0         | 0       | 1          | 0              |0       |
| 4         | 0     | 0     | 0         | 0       | 0          | 1              |0       |
```

Note that none of the patients in this first table have headache but table 2 does have a column for headache filled with 0s. I have a list of all symptoms I want to include as columns in a separate table. (let's call that table symptom: The symptom table has only two columns : symptomName and symptomID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *crosstab* query:

```sql
TRANSFORM 
    Count(Symptoms.SymptomStartDate)
SELECT 
    Symptoms.PatientID
FROM 
    Symptoms
GROUP BY 
    Symptoms.PatientID
PIVOT 
    Symptoms.SymptomName 
    IN ('Fever','Cough','ChestPain','DryEyes','SoreThroat','AnotherSymptom','Headache');
```

Apply this format to the *Format* property of field *SymptomStartDate*:

```
0;;;0
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. 
What is the SQL server equivalent of this querry? I'm doing some work on SQL server as well. Maybe I should open another question for that?

Comment: Yes, put a new question with a reference to this.